# Backslash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my javascript code I have

```
onchange="document.getElementById('user_name').value =  
 document.getElementById('theDomain').value + '\\' +
 document.getElementById('fake_user_name').value"
```

here backslash doesn't work. What is the problem?
How should I write it?

example:
I want to have "x.com\joe" by using domain name(x) and fakeusername (joe) but the result I get is just joe when I use '\'

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on your results?  What is the expected value?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it "doesn't work", what happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Works well for me: http://jsbin.com/exaze3 , your problem is probably somewhere else. Is the code written directly in HTML source code, or are you writing it in another language? If so, you may need `'\\\\'`.

Comment: I want to have "x.com\joe" by using domain name(x) and fakeusername (joe) but the result I get is just joe when I use '\\'

Comment: @erasmus - try to edit the question to add these details. What happens when you use `+ '-' +`? What if you just used `document.getElementById('theDomain').value`? How do you explain your code working in the link I gave?

Comment: @Kobi, thanks for example. I don't know why but my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say it's in your JavaScript code rather than as an attribute on an HTML element,

```
onchange="document.getElementById('user_name').value =
    document.getElementById('theDomain').value + '\\' +
    document.getElementById('fake_user_name').value"
```

Is setting a string value, delimited by `""`. As the `\\` is in a string, the value of the string is

```
document.getElementById('user_name').value = 
document.getElementById('theDomain').value + '\' +
document.getElementById('fake_user_name').value
```

which means that when that string is run as code, it is no longer valid - there is only one backslash, which escapes the closing single quote.

Either double-escape the back-slash (`'\\\\'`):

```
onchange="document.getElementById('user_name').value =
    document.getElementById('theDomain').value + '\\\\' + 
    document.getElementById('fake_user_name').value"
```

or **use a function as an event handler** instead of an evaluated string.

Answer (score 1):

Pete Kirkham is correct: use a function instead of the string.

```
element.onchange=function(){
    var domain = document.getElementById('theDomain').value,
        name = document.getElementById('fake_user_name').value;
    document.getElementById('user_name').value = domain + "\\" + name;
};
```